# Add confirm button in vuejs-datepicker

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs-datepicker

I'm interested in the question, can I add a date selection confirmation button on the calendar? I use vuejs-datepicker (vue version 2)

In the component itself, I found only slots for adding elements before or after the input, but I can’t add content to the calendar itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only [one slot](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/PickerDay.vue#L3) in vuejs-datepicker - and it is above the calendar. You may need to fork the component and change it to suit your needs.